# Changing View Controller without storing previous one in memory

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I am relatively new to swift.

I have been working on this problem for a while and despite research not found an answer.

This is what my main.storyboard looks like:

[image: Main.Storyboard]

My game is a levels based game as you can see. The problem is that every time I change level the memory usage goes up suggesting the program is storing the previous level:

[image: Memory Usage]

For the segue between the view controllers I am using present modally.

Am I using the correct type of segue or should I be somehow removing the previous view controller from memory?

any help would be massively appreciated as this has been very frustrating for a very long time now!!

Cheers :)

Comment: Probably you create a retain cycle that consumes your RAM or you don't remove an unused new (right) view controller. You have to share your code.

Comment: Difficult to share code as I created the segues on the main storyboard page. Any idea how I might be able to prevent a retain cycle?

Answer (score 0):

To navigate from game ViewController (3-rd screen) to levels ViewController (2-nd screen) you must use `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` method.

Comment: when I click the button for next level using 'dismiss' I get a warning saying that the view is not in the window hierarchy. It also doesn't go to the next level - instead just returns to the page of levels view.

Comment: What do you mean by “go to the next level”?

Comment: In my actual level view controller I have a function that checks which level it is. So by clicking the 'next level' it adds 1 to the level and then segues to itself.

Comment: segue to itself will cause a memory leak. Why do you want to reload ViewController? Why can't you start the next level in the same VC?

Comment: It's so that I can run through all the lines of code again - as each level has a different set-up. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Extract code which setups a new level in a separate function and call this function when you press `nextLevel` button.

Comment: just managed to sort this, cheers. What about the issue of lost memory when changing view controller? as in to go to the levels page

Comment: To navigate from `game` to `levels` you use `present modally` segue. It is incorrect. You should call `dismiss()` inside game ViewController.